# Creating a method class to remove element from generic array list

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I am currently learning how to manipulate generic Array Lists. My professor provided a skeleton of the following program, and as a way to practice, I am attempting to fill in the methods. However, I am running into trouble with the segment:

```
public E remove(int index) {
return this.remove((Integer)index); //This is an attempt
}//end remove
```

Which throws a StackOverFlow Exception at runtime.
Below I have the full code (not including interface and driver):

```
package array;    
public class DHArrayList<E> implements BareArray<E>{
private int arraySize;   // size is an indication of position in array
private int capacity;
private E[] myArray;
private static final int INITIAL_CAPACITY = 10;
//Once you have created an ArrayList, you can ignore the capacity in all programming that follows

public DHArrayList(){
    capacity = INITIAL_CAPACITY; 
    /*INITIAL_CAPACITY is the number of items that ArrayList will allocate to 
    begin with as the internal storage of items.*/
    arraySize = 0;
}//end default constructor

public DHArrayList(int capacity){
    this.capacity = capacity;
    this.arraySize = 0; //size denotes array indices that are used
    myArray = (E[]) new Object[this.capacity]; 
}//end constructor with parameter

public void add(E a) { //default, will add a value to the end of the list.
       if(arraySize < capacity){ //which entails that there exists space
           //size value gives the index of first free location
           myArray[arraySize] = a; 
           arraySize++;   //updates size
       }//end if
       else{
           System.out.println("Array full. Reallocating . . .");
           this.reallocate();   //Change capacity of array
           this.add(a);
       }//end else       
}//end add

private void reallocate(){ // doubles size of array
    this.capacity *= 2;
    //new array, doubled capacity
    E[] newArray = (E[])new Object[this.capacity]; 
    for(int i = 0; i < this.arraySize; i++){
        newArray[i] = myArray[i]; // reload values
    }//end for

    //Reassigns the myArray pointer to the newArray reference point.
    this.myArray = newArray;
}//end reallocate

public void add(int index, E a) {
    if(index < 0 || index > arraySize){
        System.out.println("Invalid index."); 
        return;
    }//end if

    /*Reusable code from the add method above, 
        else-IF index is at end of list.*/   
    else if(index==arraySize){
        this.add(a);
    }//end else if

    else{
        // Ensure there is space, then move elements and insert.
        if(this.capacity == this.arraySize) {
            this.reallocate();
        }//end if

        //move data
        for (int i = arraySize; i > index; i--){
            this.myArray[i] = this.myArray[i-1]; //shifts to right.
        }//end for

        //Insert data into specified index
        this.myArray[index] = a;
        arraySize++;
    }//end else
}

public E remove(int index) {
    return this.remove((Integer)index); 
}//end remove

public E get(int index) {
    return myArray[index];
}//end get

public void set(int index, E a){ 
}//end set

public int getSize() {
    return 0;
}//end getSize

public int indexOf(E a) {
    return 0;
}//end indexOf

public void display(){
   System.out.println("The contents of the array are ");
   for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
       System.out.print(this.myArray[i] +", ");
    }//end for
}//end display
}//end DHArrayList
```

Comment: You haven't written any real implementation of the `remove` method.  You're going to have to do all the shifting of elements in the array, etcetera that you have in the `add` method, and figure out exactly what the right way to do it is for the `remove` method.  This is going to be complicated, at least as complicated as the `add` method.

Comment: You receive the StackOverflow Exception because your `remove()` method just calls itself over and over again, until you are out of stack space. Otherwise @LouisWasserman has already provided the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
public E remove(int index) {
  return this.remove((Integer)index); // This is an attempt
}
```

What you've got here is an infinite [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)). Your boxed class `Integer` gets automatically unboxed to `int` and you end up with the method which calls itself indefinitely (well until it runs out of stack memory, that's why you get StackOverflowException)

`Remove` method has to be similar (code vise) to `add` method just opposite :)